# Trigger in Oracle giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

This is my sql code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PLACE_NO_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON UHA_LEASE
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  INSERT INTO UHA_TEMPVAL SELECT PLACE_NO FROM UHA_RESHALL; 
  INSERT INTO UHA_TEMPVAL SELECT PLACE_NO FROM UHA_GENERAL;
  IF(:NEW.PLACE_NO NOT IN UHA_TEMPVAL.TEMP_VALUE AND :NEW.PLACE_NO IS NOT NULL) THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-10001, 'PLACE_NO MUST BE IN UHA_RESHALL OR IN UHA_GENERAL OR NULL');
  END IF;
  DELETE FROM UHA_TEMPVAL;
END;
```

This is giving these errors:

```
Error(4,27): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UHA_TEMPVAL" when expecting one of the following:     ( The symbol "(" was substituted for "UHA_TEMPVAL" to continue. 
Error(4,69): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:     ) , and or as The symbol ")" was substituted for "THEN" to continue.
```

Can someone help me understand why these errors are occurring? It's especially odd because row 4 ends at column 60.

Thanks!

Comment: verify the table "UHA_TEMPVAL" exists:  `select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'UHA_TEMPVAL';`  Also, not really sure what you're doing, but using a trigger to stuff values in other tables is not really a recommended way of using triggers. :(

Comment: Ahh wait, my bad.  I thought it was erroring on the INSERT ... looks like it's failing on the IF ...   you can't do this:  `UHA_TEMPVAL.TEMP_VALUE`  you can't access a table value like a variable. You need to store that into a variable first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to enforce referential integrity from a child table to either of two parent tables. You don't really need to insert and delete from a temporary table; you can count how many rows match in either table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PLACE_NO_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON UHA_LEASE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  CNT NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO CNT
  FROM (
    SELECT PLACE_NO FROM UHA_RESHALL
    WHERE PLACE_NO = :NEW.PLACE_NO
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PLACE_NO FROM UHA_GENERAL
    WHERE PLACE_NO = :NEW.PLACE_NO
  );

  IF :NEW.PLACE_NO IS NOT NULL AND CNT = 0 THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-10001,
      'PLACE_NO MUST BE IN UHA_RESHALL OR IN UHA_GENERAL OR NULL');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

You could choose to only run the query if the `:NEW.PLACE_NO` is not null but it probably won't make much difference if the columns are indexed.